# Database (Azure or Oracle) - Most efficient accurate way of detecting incremental changes?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, azure, etl

So in the past for our ETL processes we used to do a column by column lookup and comparison. This way worked for us for a while and no one bothered to go back to take a look at how to make it more efficient.

Recently we noticed that our job run times are starting to creep up so this led to some discussion and one suggestion to optimize our process was that we use "hashing".

From my limited time with Googling I am getting some mixed messages about the benefits to hashing.

Now I know by doing a column by column look up it seems to be a tried and true method, simple to understand/implement and is relatively accurate.

With hashing - How would this be any better?

Logically I would think that instead of comparing multiple rows & columns with hashing we could just be comparing multiple rows and one single column for example.

But there is mention that there could be "clashes" or "collision" with hashing - So could this lead to inaccuracies or challenges trouble shooting?

Before we start tearing things apart I just wanted to see if I may have missed anything

**EDIT 2022-07-16**

When I refer to Azure I used it a bit generically as we are planning on using Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse for our data movement/ETL/ELT. So we would be using BOTH Azure SQL Server and also Azure Data Lake Gen2 (and eventually other Azure services). Its quite a few moving pieces, in particular with ADLS - One item we were trying to figure out is how we can compare differences between "files". That led us down a rabbit hole of "can we use hashing? What is hashing?"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Azure isn't a database. Commercial databases already have change tracking mechanisms whether it's Changed Data Capture or Change Tracking. They don't use hashing because they don't need to - they know when a modification was made and record it. Worst case you can use triggers to capture those changes yourself

Comment: SQL Server's [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) is available in all versions and editions, including Express. It's also lighter than [CDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) because it doesn't capture the entire row that changed, only the primary keys and the reason. CDC is only available in Standard and up

Comment: Oracle is ... [interesting](https://bryteflow.com/oracle-cdc-change-data-capture-13-things-to-know/) as it had several CDC technologies over the years, some free and some requiring an extra license. The free features were deprecated and replaced with newer licensed ones.

Comment: Wikipedia has a page on [Change Data Capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture). If your database runs on a cloud provider it's quite possible the cloud provider also offers a CDC or event streaming service beyond the database's own CDC mechanism.

Comment: Which database are you actually using? It matters. Different products have different features. In SQL Server for example, instead of trying to upsert a target table you could load all data into a new "staging" table then use partition switching to swap one table with the other instantaneously.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Apologies for the lack of detail, I edited my OP with more info. Our current backend is 90% Oracle relational databases. Yep Oracle was messy to maintain, hence our interest in Azure SQL Server. In my very basic minds eye I was trying to figure out how we can go back and forth between Oracle and Azure without relying too heavily on built in CDC features. We were debating how we can make the process more "generic". In particular with Azure Data Lake - Not sure how to compare differences in for example data files that are CSV? In comes the idea of "hashing" - Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Hashing is normally better as you only compare one column, that contains the hash, rather than every column.

Collisions can occur with hashes but very rarely. and it depends on the hash function you use. You would need to research your chosen hash function, determine under what conditions you might get collisions and then decide whether that was a concern given your particular circumstances

Comment: I admit I dont know a lot about hashing, just trying to wrap my head around the idea now - But are there any recommended hashes? I am assuming differences between hashes may be the possibility of clashes and speed? When I say speed - I am guessing certain hashes may be "faster" compared to others, would that be something that needs to also be taken into consideration?